# PHP inside Angular Results

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I know that Angular is rendered client side, and PHP is a server side script but is there any way I can combine the two - it's all very new for me.

For example, this angular response works just fine.

```
<li ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit" data-name="{{data.customerName}}" class="myli">
           <strong>{{data.customerName}}</strong><br />
           {{data.addressLine1}}, {{data.city}}, {{data.state}}, {{data.postalCode}}, {{data.country}}<br />
           <code>{{data.creditLimit}}</code>
</li>
```

But what if I wanted to add some PHP logic into it, is there a way I can go about doing this? I appreciate there are javascript equivalents I can use for many features (case:select etc). but not for md5 for example. One of my aims is to load a gravatar image in the resulting li.

```
<li ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit" data-name="{{data.customerName}}" class="myli">
           <strong>{{data.customerName}}</strong><br />
           {{data.addressLine1}}, {{data.city}}, {{data.state}}, {{data.postalCode}}, {{data.country}}<br />
           <code>{{data.creditLimit}}</code>
           <?php if("{{data.creditLimit}}" >= 1000){ // Do Something } ?>
</li>
```

Comment: yep you can use with echo; on the severside.  But you may be mistaking server side ( php ) from client side ( javascript ) one runs on the server one runs on the end users browser, which is a big difference.  Sever side logic would be interpreted when the page is rendered, not in real time.  Once the page is served it is the domain of client side languages ( such as JavaScript )

Comment: https://github.com/wallin/angular-gravatar ?

Comment: Additionally, client side logic is perfectly acceptable.  For instance say you have some javascript that only applies to users that are logged in, why even include that code when a user is not logged in.  This can only be achieved serverside.  However you cannot expect php logic to react to actions taken on the client side in real time ( short of using ajax )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a shot at `ng-if` directive. It is different than show / hide because it actually removes or recreates the dom element.

```
<div ng-if="data.creditLimit >= 1000"><?php ... ?></div>
```

Give that a shot and let me know how it works out.

Comment: This is great, I didn't know the ng-if directive existed! Thanks for highlighting this to me.

Answer (score 1):

For your example of

> but not for md5 for example

You have 3 choices that I see,

- calculate the md5 serverside, and pass it into a variable or attribute

  `var hash = '<?php echo md5( $something ); ?>';`
- Use ajax to send it to the sever, calculate it and send it back to the client.
- Or find a JavaScript solution ( which exists ) such as

https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5

Comment: Thank you so much for your references and links, these will all prove very helpful and exactly what I was after.  I'm a bit overwhelmed by the great responses from yourself and @ODelibalta.